# ElasticSearch - Search results are not coming in ascending order

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Am searching for some keyword using java API in ElasticSearch and am getting some bunch of results for my search keyword. But my exact search keyword is not coming at the top of the results.

For Example : `Keyword : AB-7000-8003`

Am getting the below response for my search keyword.

```
[
    {
        "code": "AB-7000-8003-W",
        "id": "11569",
    },
    {
        "code": "AB-7000-8003",
        "id": "11573",
    },
    {
        "code": "AB-7000-8003-WK",
        "id": "11565",
    },
    {
        "code": "AB-7000-8003S",
        "id": "11557",
    },
    {
        "code": "AB-7000-8003-k",
        "id": "11569",
    }
]
```

Am Expected Result like below in ascending order and my exact search keyword should be at the top of the result:

```
[

    {
        "code": "AB-7000-8003",
        "id": "11573",
    },
    {
        "code": "AB-7000-8003-k",
        "id": "11569",
    },
    {
        "code": "AB-7000-8003S",
        "id": "11557",
    },
    {
        "code": "AB-7000-8003-W",
        "id": "11569",
    },
    {
        "code": "AB-7000-8003-WK",
        "id": "11565",
    }
]
```

Please find my code below :

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(PRODUCTS_INDEX);
searchRequest.types(TYPE);
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();

QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("product_code", code));


searchSourceBuilder.query(qb);
searchSourceBuilder.size(8000);
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);

SearchResponse searchResponse = null;
try {
    searchResponse = SearchEngineClient.getInstance().search(searchRequest);
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
    ExceptionUtils.handle(e);
}
```

Am using ElasticSearch 6.2.3 version.

Comment: I do believe that *AB-7000-8003S* should be indexed second in the list and then the *AB-7000-8003-k* third :)

Answer (score 0):

Queries are sorted by scroe
`scroe = tf * idf * norm`
With "norms" : {" enabled ": false} after closing, score, no matter what the length of the field of document, scores are the same. Check your index mapping